# How to 'undo' this small function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using this to adapt my text which then gets inserted into a mysql db:

```
$ad_text=nl2br(wordwrap($_POST['annonsera_text'], 60, "\n", true));
```

When users wish to change their posting, they click a link on my page, and a form opens.
In this form, the textarea where I fetch the info from mysql, I am displaying the text again.
Only problem is, the text itself contains '`<br>`' tags. That is, it shows up EXACTLY as it looks in the mysql table field.

How can I undo the function above so that the `<br>` tags are removed again?
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't wordwrap the text before storing it the db. Do that only when it's needed. (for example just before printing it on a webpage)

Comment: Indeed... databases are for data. Scripting and markup languages are for formatting. That way if you change your mind down the road, it'll be easier for ya. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not insert your *clean* unmodified text into the database, then html-ify it only when displaying?

Comment: Displaying the text would most likely happen more often than editing. The OP's approach reduces work required for the normal case.

Comment: What the heck? Why was this answer chosen? It doesn't solve his current problem it just tells him how to fix it for the future...

Answer (score 1):

This will be more future-proof, I think:

```
$ad_text = preg_replace('/<br\s*?/?>/i', "\n", $ad_text);
```

You never know... the nl2br script may or may not put spaces in between the `<br` and the `/>` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A quick find and replace would do the trick:

```
$ad_text = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $ad_text);
```

...essentially replacing all found breaks with newlines.